# A PC made himself king, are there any rules for this?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Are there any rules or rulebooks to guide handling a PC being king? I ask because I want to know if there is anything special rules for a king PC, since one of my players has wound up as one. It does not have to be in the core books.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a moment to check out the [tour] and the [help] to get an idea of how things work around here.

Comment: When you ask “are there any core rulebooks for a PC being king”, what kind of rules are you looking for? Economics rules? New personal character options? Guidance for DMs? There are lots of *different kinds* of rules that you *might* be hoping for, but your question doesn't make it clear what kind of rules you feel you're lacking.